# Not able to use renamed Title column in a calculated field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I'm trying to set a formula that uses the Title field which was renamed. But when I save the calculated field the SPO shows an error telling me that I'm using a field that does not exist (!!!).

[image]

The [Projeto] column is the renamed Title column.
And the error is :
[image]

Comment: In the formula, replace ; (semicolon) with , (comma)

Comment: I have tested that too, but the problem is related to the SharePoint not recognizing the renamed Title column.

Answer (score 1):

Per my test, I can reproduce your issue in my end. To solve this issue, do not change the name, continue to use the title and it will work normally. You could have a try.

Comment: Thanks for you reply... I tried to rename it back to "Title", but did not work. I must use this existing list, so do you think I won't be able to set up this column while this bug is up?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce this issue in SharePoint Online List.

Steps:

1. Renamed the [Title] column to **[Cal-Title]** and filled in with dummy values
2. The list already has a column named **[Countries]** with Country Names
3. Created a **Calculated** column, named [CalcOfRenamedTitle], with the following formula.

4. The formula outputs the expected calculated values without any issues. See the screenshot below

```
=IF(LEN([Cal-Title])=4,LEFT([Cal-Title],3)&"-"&Countries,[Cal-Title]&"<>"&Countries)
```

[image]